# Chef: Generate a self-signed CA

Tags: ruby, openssl, certificate, chef-infra

I would like to do the following with chef:

1. Generate a self-signed root CA (.cer)
2. Generate a certificate request  (.csr)
3. Sign that certificate request by the root CA and obtain the file (.crt)

How I could do that using chef? I've seen that cookbook https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/openssl but there doesn't appear how to sign a certificate.

Following is the code that I actually use:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3650 -x509 -nodes -out root.cer
openssl req -newkey rsa:1024 -nodes -out vault.csr -keyout vault.key 
openssl ca -batch -config root-ca.conf -notext -in vault.csr -out vault.crt

sudo update-ca-trust enable
mv root.cer /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
sudo update-ca-trust extract
```

Comment: I would highly recommend looking at higher level tools like certstrap or easypki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want chef to manage CA/PKI look at [ssl certificate cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ssl_certificate) it may be more suitable. Although, more complicated than openssl cookbook.

Comment: Thanks, it was quite easy with this cookbook!